# creating & setting a wpf window gradient background via c# code

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

having a dynamically created window via C# I am trying to assign it a gradient background but I got stuck reproducing the  XAML via c# code

created window (I tried to remove as much irrelevant code as possible)

```
static LinearGradientBrush backgroundLinearBrush = null;

static Window MsgBox(int parlnNum, string parflPath, string parMethodName, string Msgbx_Contnt)
{
    var w_mbx = new Window(); w_mbx.Topmost = true;
    w_mbx.Width = 1000; w_mbx.Height = 179;

   //from an online example I tried adding the rectangle
   // as the gradient owner- not sure if this is the way to go
   Rectangle GradientRectangle = new Rectangle() { Width = w_mbx.Width, Height = w_mbx.Height };

if (backgroundLinearBrush == null)
{

   GradientStopCollection gradientStopsLinearBrush = new GradientStopCollection();
    gradientStopsLinearBrush.Add(new GradientStop((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#EF63BADF"), 0.0));
    gradientStopsLinearBrush.Add(new GradientStop((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#E856B7C9"), 0.555));
    gradientStopsLinearBrush.Add(new GradientStop((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#C543C0DB"), 0.333));
    gradientStopsLinearBrush.Add(new GradientStop((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#E734ABDA"), 0.444));
    gradientStopsLinearBrush.Add(new GradientStop((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#927FE2E2"), 0.777));
    gradientStopsLinearBrush.Add(new GradientStop((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#E974CFC1"), 0.555));
    gradientStopsLinearBrush.Add(new GradientStop((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#D076C5EB"), 0.275));

    LinearGradientBrush backgroundLinearBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(gradientStopsLinearBrush)
    {
        StartPoint = new Point(0, 0.5),
        EndPoint = new Point(1, 0.5)
    };

    GradientRectangle.Fill = backgroundLinearBrush;

}
```

then construction of elements within the window

```
Grid g = new Grid();
Grid.SetRow(GradientRectangle, 1);
Grid.SetColumn(GradientRectangle, 1);

StackPanel spM = new StackPanel();
TextBlock TblckErrMsg = new TextBlock();
TblckErrMsg.Name = "Tblck_ErrMsg";
TextBlock TblckLine = new TextBlock();
TblckLine.Name = "Tblck_Line";
TblckLine.Text = "[GoToError]";
TblckLine.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler((s, e) => TblckLine_MouseDown(s, e, parflPath, parlnNum));

spM.Children.Add(TblckErrMsg);
spM.Children.Add(TblckLine);
g.Children.Add(spM);
w_mbx.Content = g;
return w_mbx;

}
```

I guess there's some missing step here that is the cause I couldn't achieve the requested result.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make a style for it? Basically:

- Define the style in XAML, and then
- `myDynamicWindow.SetResourceReference(Window.Style, "NameOfDefinedStyle");` (which is the equivalent of `<Window Style="{DynamicResource NameOfDefinedStyle}"/>`).

If you have multiple styles for windows and don't want to copy/paste template, define one style containing properties they all should share and base individual new ones off the original. That could be done with the following syntax:

```
<Style x:Key="WindowBase" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <!-- Shared properties -->
</Style>
<Style x:Key="DynamicWindowStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource WindowBase}">
    <!-- You can set a unique background gradient here -->
</Style>
```

Note: Changing a Window's background is not as simple as changing a Grid's. If you do not have a template to override the default for Window controls, let me know and I'll post a full, working sample.